# Oracle SQL insert into table a user ID and a value of a list of strings

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I would like to do the following but I lack the knowledge of Oracle SQL to do this.

I wish to give a userid as a string, and then a list of strings as a parameter to a procedure.

In the procedure I wish to make an insert into a table for each value in that list, together with the same user ID each time.

My questions:

I can't find an example of what to declare the input parameter as to make it a list. Do I need to make it a long varchar? I roughly know what the max length could be if the list is filled out entirely, but i was wondering if there is a data type for a sort of list?

How do I loop trough the list.

I see a lot of examples like this:

```
FOR r IN ('The', 'Quick', 'brown', 'fox')
LOOP
    // Do stuff
END LOOP;
```

So does this mean I should provide my list as a single string with comma separate values? I was wondering if there are other ways to do this.

Comment: *Do I make a call for each user/ region pair?* Sure, why not? *Or can I send a list of strings over and solve this in the procedure?* Sure, why not? This question isn't a great fit for the site because we prefer questions that can be answered ratehr than just discussed - this question seems to be predominantly garnering opinion

Comment: If I do send the list over, how do I go about that in the SQL code then. I have never seen an example iterating over a list and doing an insert for each value encountered.

Comment: Well, it works pretty much like you say... And that question IS something that can be answered

Comment: I am going to try and reword the question better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (PL/)SQL option you might want to consider.

For testing purposes, I've created a `TEST` table which will contain the `ID` - `VALUE` pairs. The procedure accepts two parameters, both are strings:

- `ID` will be common for all values
- `VALUE` is a comma-separated values list. Although you can pass a collection, I'd suggest you to use VARCHAR2 as it is quite simple to maintain

`SELECT` within the procedure uses a *hierarchical query* with regular expressions; its purpose is to split that comma-separated values string into rows so that you could insert each value into its own row. Doing so, you don't even need a loop. Besides, that `SELECT` would work even if you run it *standalone*, but - you want a procedure.

OK, here it goes:

```
SQL> create table test (id varchar2(10), value varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_ins (par_id    in varchar2,
  2                                     par_value in varchar2)
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    insert into test (id, value)
  6      select par_id,
  7             trim(regexp_substr(par_value, '[^,]+', 1, level))
  8      from dual
  9      connect by level <= regexp_count(par_value, ',') + 1;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> begin
  2    p_ins('A', 'The, quick, brown fox, runs, or, whatever, it does');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

ID         VALUE
---------- --------------------
A          The
A          quick
A          brown fox
A          runs
A          or
A          whatever
A          it does

7 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute the same insert N times with N different strings

```
string[] things = new[]{"foo", "bar", "baz");

SomeSqlCommand sql = new SomeSqlCommand("INSERT INTO table(a, b) VALUES(@a, @b)", "some connection string");
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", "fixed value");
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", "dummy value - will change in loop");

sql.Connection.Open();

foreach(string thing in things)
{
  sql.Parameters["@b"].Value = thing;
  sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

sql.Connection.Close();
```

Omitted using etc for clarity; basic premise: set up a parameterised SQL, set the parameter values, execute, change values, execute again...

When I used Oracle, parameter names were preceded by a colon; no idea if that's still true. Treat this as pseudocode (it's more like SQLServer syntax) and merge the concept into your existing Oracle style

Comment: Thanks, I tried to reword my question so it is more clear what I mean, and that it is anwserable; The part that I have difficulties with is inside of the stored procedure, the querry code itself.